# Using PL/SQL, how can I create a trigger to validate a field based on character length?

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper, string-length

One practical use of a trigger is validation within a single table (that is, the validation 
can be performed by using columns in the table being modified). Create a trigger 
that validates that the summary is being inserted correctly, that is, that the summary 
is actually the first 12 characters of the content followed by “…”. The trigger should 
reject an insert that does not have a valid summary value. Verify the trigger works by 
issuing two insert commands – one with a correct summary, and one with an 
incorrect summary. List out the Post table after the inserts to show one insert was 
blocked and the other succeeded.

For more context, there is a "content" field, in which the "summary" field pulls the first 12 characters from "content" and follows it with ... (3 dots) for a total of 15 characters.

Example:
Content = 'I had a great trip'
Then summary = 'I had a grea...'

So far this is all I have:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER summary_length
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON Post
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :NEW.summary != SUBSTR(content, 1, 12) || '...' THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Summary must only include the first 12 characters of Content, followed by ...');
   END IF;
END;
```

I get the following errors:

Error(1,4): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(1,30): PLS-00201: identifier 'CONTENT' must be declared

The tutorial for my class shows this example, however this example appears so much easier than enforcing that the first 12 characters of Summary = the first 12 characters of Content, followed by "..."

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER no_neg_bal_trg
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON Customer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF :NEW.customer_total < 0 THEN
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Customer balance cannot be negative.');
 END IF;
END;
```

I'm really struggling to figure this out, any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: This is a bad use of a trigger.  You should be learning about `check` constraints.

Comment: While I'm sure you are right, I don't have much of a choice given this is a class assignment :/

Comment: The clue is in the error message. Try `:new.content`. By the way, we normally refer to "columns", not "fields".

Comment: This is why triggers should be regulated to an advanced course. Not because they are themselves difficult (normally), but because instructors do not know there proper use (virtually always). This then leads their students without knowing when to use them and a desire to use triggers later in production where they should not be used.  Guess I need to get off my soap-box.

Answer (score 0):

use :new.content since you are using new value

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer>>

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER summary_validation_trg
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON Post
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.summary != SUBSTR(:new.content, 1, 12) || '...' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,'Summary not equal to 12 characters');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).